# Parsing and sorting keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I created the following dictionary:

```
code dictionary =  {u'News; comment; negative': u'contradictory about news', u'News; comment': u'something about news'}
```

I now want to write some Python code that goes through the dictionary's keys and separates out the codes and their corresponding values. So for the first element in the dictionary, I want to end up with:

```
News: 'contradictory about news', 'something about news'
comment: 'contradictory about news', 'something about news'
negative: 'contradictory about news'
```

The end result can be a dictionary, list, or tab or comma-separated text.

You can see my attempt to do this here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
f = open('transcript.xml','r')
soup = Soup(f)
#print soup.prettify()


#searches text for all w:commentrangestart tags and makes a dictionary that matches ids with text
textdict = {}
for i in soup.find_all('w:commentrangestart'):
        # variable 'key' is assigned to the tag id
        key = i.parent.contents[1].attrs['w:id']
        key = str(key)
        #variable 'value' is assigned to the tag's text
        value= ''.join(i.nextSibling.findAll(text=True))
        # key / value pairs are added to the dictionary 'textdict'
        textdict[key]=value
print "Transcript Text = " , textdict

# makes a dictionary that matches ids with codes        
codedict = {}
for i in soup.find_all('w:comment'):
        key = i.attrs['w:id']
        key = str(key)
        value= ''.join(i.findAll(text=True))
        codedict[key]=value
print "Codes = ", codedict

# makes a dictionary that matches all codes with text
output = {}
for key in set(textdict.keys()).union(codedict.keys()):
        print "key= ", key
        txt = textdict[key]
        print "txt = ", txt
        ct = codedict[key]
        print "ct= ", ct
        output[ct] = txt
        #print "output = ", output
print "All code dictionary = ", output

#codelist={}
#for key in output:
#   codelist =key.split(";")
#print "codelist= " , codelist


code_negative = {}
code_news = {}
print output.keys()
for i in output:
    if 'negative' in output.keys():
        print 'yay'
        code_negative[i]=textdict[i]
        print 'text coded negative: ' , code_negative
    if 'News' in i:
        code_news[i]=textdict[i]
        print 'text coded News: ' ,code_news
```

For some reason though, I keep getting a key error when I run the last function:

```
code_negative = {}
code_news = {}
for i in output:
    if 'negative' in output.keys():
        code_negative[i]=textdict[i]
    print 'text coded negative: ' , code_negative
if 'News' in i:
    code_news[i]=textdict[i]
    print 'text coded News: ' ,code_news
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: continually iterate through what you want using a split function...something like a for loop where you then return i.split(';'). That should allow you to iterate through what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work, if I understood the problem correctly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in code_dictionary.viewitems():
    for item in k.split('; '):
        out[item].append(v)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
output = {u'News; comment; negative': u'contradictory about news', u'News; comment': u'something about news'}
negatives = []
comments = []
news = []
for k, v in output.items():
    key_parts = k.split('; ')
    key_parts = [part.lower() for part in key_parts]
    if 'negative' in key_parts:
        negatives.append(v)
    if 'news' in key_parts:
        news.append(v)
    if 'comment' in key_parts:
        comments.append(v)
```